# 'dataset name is missing' when combining TABLE_DATE_RANGE with UNNEST

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I used to do a query on a single-day GA table like this:

```
FROM
  `<id>.ga_sessions_intraday_20170101`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS h
```

This works perfectly, I can get all the data I need.
Now I tried querying a Date-range;

```
FROM
   TABLE_DATE_RANGE([<id>.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD'), TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Which works, but when I try it with the UNNEST(hits), it gives this error:

**Error: Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing.**

for

```
FROM
   TABLE_DATE_RANGE([<id>.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD'), TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD')),
   UNNEST(hits) AS h
```

How could this be solved? And why does it behave this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TABLE_DATE_RANGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix) is table wildcard function supported in BigQuery Legacy SQL, whereas [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix) function supported in BigQuery Standard SQL

You should use [_TABLE_SUFFIX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix) that is also supported in Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ...
FROM `<id>.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170110'
```